# Finding out if a column is NOT NULL

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a column in my DB which is currently defined as `NOT NULL`.
I would like to update this column to allow `NULLs`.

I have the following script to do this however I would like to check first if the column is already `NULL` (or `NOT NULL`), as it may have been changed previously.

```
 ALTER TABLE [dbo].[aud]
 ALTER COLUMN [actname] nvarchar(50) NULL
```

Any help appreciated.

Comment: Why do you want to check? If the column is already nullable, you can safely run your alter statement, it will have no effect but not give any error either.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Use **COLUMNPROPERTY** to get column property . You may write something like

```
SELECT COLUMNPROPERTY(OBJECT_ID('dbo.aud'),'actname','AllowsNull') AS 'AllowsNull';
```

For more information please visit this  [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174968.aspx)

Comment: +1 Neat. Is this more efficient than the `sys` tables? Not that efficiency will be a massive overhead in this scenario.

Comment: I think so though i am not 100% sure ..:)

Answer (score 7):

```
select is_nullable from sys.columns c inner join sys.tables t on
t.object_id = c.object_id where t.name = 'aud' and c.name = 'actname'
```

Will give you a `BIT` representing whether it is nullable or not.

So you could switch on this like

```
IF EXISTS(SELECT * from sys.columns c inner join sys.tables t on
    t.object_id = c.object_id where t.name = 'aud' and c.name = 'actname' AND
    is_nullable = 1)
    BEGIN
      --What to do if nullable
    END
ELSE
    BEGIN
      --What to do if not nullable
    END
END
```

That of course assumes that the table and column exist at all...

Answer (score 3):

There isn't really a need to do that, because if it's already Nullable, changing a column from Nullable to Nullable will have no negative effect.

However you can do it with this query:

```
SELECT is_nullable 
FROM sys.columns 
WHERE object_id=object_id('YourTable') AND name = 'yourColumn'
```